# Google maps web geo location not working on nexus 5 android 4.4.4?

Tags: android, maps, google-geolocation

I have a Nexus 5 and I recently got the 4.4.4 update.

Since then the geo location functionality on my site has stopped working on my phone. It works on desktop machine and other phone like iPhone:

http://thesalesite.com.au/#/search

It should show your location relative to some shops (test data)

I have also checked the Google maps site and it doesn't seem to be working for that either:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

Both sites ask to use my location.

Is anyone able to confirm this issue?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like there is a bug in Chrome for Android. I found a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=175909) on Chromium. You might consider to "star" it to follow the progress.

Comment: Thanks very much for the update Andrew. Apologies for the very late response.